Cookie neither being set on browser nor being sent to the backend with requests but are being set by the the backend in the response header
Hi everyone so I had a backend on localhost:5000 where i first logged in and sent access and refresh token in cookies and they are being sent in the api response header but not being set neither on the browser nor being sent with other requests, with what I know I tried multiple approaches still no result.
Here's what I have checked,
Frontend is Nextjs so running on localhost:3000

including credentials in the api requests

 const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof taskSchema>) => {
    console.log(values);

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/v1/task/createTask", values, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });

      console.log(res.data);

      onClose();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };


Proxy server

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination: "http://localhost:5000/api/:path*",
      },
    ];
  },
};
export default nextConfig;



On the backend running on localhost:5000

cors settings


app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);


Cookie options settings

const options = {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  sameSite: "None",
};

I am using cookie parser for here

VerifyJwt middleware

import { User } from "../models/user.model.js";
import { ApiError } from "../utils/ApiError.js";
import { asyncHandler } from "../utils/asyncHandler.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const verifyJwt = asyncHandler(async (req, _, next) => {
  try {
    const token =
      req.cookies?.accessToken ||
      req.header("Authorization")?.replace("Bearer ", "");

      console.log(token);
  
    if (!token) {
      throw new ApiError(401, "Unauthorized");
    }
  
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
  
    const user = await User.findById(decodedToken?._id).select(
      "-password -refreshToken"
    );
  
    if (!user) {
      throw new ApiError(401, "Invalid access token");
    }
  
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new ApiError(401, error?.message || "Invalid access token");
  }
});

I searched through a lot of articles but nothing seem to work. A little help would be really grateful

Allow third party cookie on browser checked

cookie not being sent with subsequent request neither so getting 401 neither being set on browser due to different domain fe and be. I want to be able to sent he cookies along with each request.

cookie should not be set as 'secure: true' under localhost environment.

I tried this I also tried a proxy configuration with nextjs rewrite still no cookies are being set

@AakashRaj where did you set the cookie? May you post the code?

You are almost right but you made a mistake with the wrong options of cookies.
so there is the correct option.
This should be true only in production with HTTPS
Adjust to "None" with secure: true if working with cross-site cookies
const options = {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: false, 
  same site: "Lax", 
};

//Send in the response
// store in local storage of browser
res.cookie('accessToken', accessToken, options);
res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, options);


Next.js is working with server-side rendering. So, you cannot directly use dom or browser functionality. It requires to wait for client-side rendering to use like the localhost function or other option is to use them inside the hook (maybe custom hook).
For example:
Hook for localhost:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    const storedValue = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    return storedValue ? JSON.parse(storedValue) : initialValue;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
}

Usage:
"use client";
import { useLocalStorage } from "./hook";


export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    const [count, setCount] = useLocalstorage('count', 0);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{count}</div>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count+1)}>Add</div>
        </div>
    );
}


I fixed it using a proxy server as I didn't want to save the token in the local or session storage or redux store either as it is not that safe
